# Attempting to create an auto populating excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I am attempting to create a spreadsheet that will have two sheets “completed daily tasks” and “daily report”. Essentially I want the first one to be updated daily and then for the second one to receive the new data each time new information is submitted. I am having an issue with the code when it comes to the date. It keeps spitting out “1/1/1900” whenever any date is submitted into “A2” from “A9:B9”

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim completedRange As Range
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    Dim nextCell As Range
    
    Set completedRange = Range("A9:H9") ' Merged cells range in Completed Daily Tasks
    Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Report") ' Change sheet name if necessary
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nextCell = reportSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) ' Find next available cell in column A
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If nextCell Is Nothing Or IsEmpty(nextCell) Then
        Set nextCell = reportSheet.Range("A2")
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, completedRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent recursive triggering
        
        ' Transfer values from merged cells to Daily Report
        reportSheet.Range("A2").Value = Range("A9").Value
        reportSheet.Range("B2").Value = Range("C9").Value
        reportSheet.Range("C2").Value = Range("E9").Value
        reportSheet.Range("D2").Value = Range("G9").Value
        
        ' Increment the next available cell in Daily Report
        If IsNumeric(nextCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
            nextCell.Value = nextCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        Else
            nextCell.Value = 1
        End If
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events
    End If
End Sub
```

I’ve tried to change the values in the VBA, formatting, and the values attached to the specific line of code. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Dates in Excel are stored as a serial number, perhaps convert then copy paste as a serial number or try some of the date functions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is writing the date correctly, and then overwriting the date incorrectly.

In `Set nextCell = reportSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`, `nextCell` will always be empty.

So `Set nextCell = reportSheet.Range("A2")` will always be executed.

The next part of your code `'Transfer values...` will correctly write the date. If you add some breakpoints you will see the correct date being written.

But then you have this code:

```
If IsNumeric(nextCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
    nextCell.Value = nextCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
Else
    nextCell.Value = 1
End If
```

Since `nextCell` is always `A2`, and I assume `A1` is blank, this code will always change `A2` to equal 0+1, which when formatted as a date is 1/01/1900.